# year and month in where clause in oracle 10g

Tags: php, oracle, oracle10g, date-format, date-formatting

I have my date in format March 2014. How do I get month and year in number format to compare it in Oracle 10g query.

```
    <?php
    $date = "March 2014";
    ?>
```

My query that I am trying to get is

```
    select EMP_NAME where month = "03" and year = "2014".
```

Here is my table structure

```
    EMP_ID  |  EMP_NAME  |  C_DATE
       1    |     ABC    |  01-FEB-14
       2    |     XYZ    |  03-MAR-14
```

Note: I am writing the coding in php

Answer (score 1):

For a sargable predicate you should avoid altering every row of data to suit the single parameter.

Instead: Adjust the parameter to suit the data

```
select
*
from your_table
where C_DATE>= to_date('March 2014','MON YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') 
and C_DATE< add_months(to_date('March 2014','MON YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'),1)
```

Note the data - C_DATE - is not affected by any function, yet you get the desired outcome (all records of March 2014); this method permits use of indexes on the field C_DATE for query efficiency.

Comment: please specify what you mean by wrong and I'll happily fix it. (that query above works in 11g as is)

Comment: I thought the function formatting strings should match the date definition of the table provided. If it works than no problem :D

Comment: Oracle dates aren't stored in a particular format - they're stored as dates, not strings.

Comment: I would do the following just in case the NLS settings for the database use non-English month names: `TO_DATE('March 2014', 'Month YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')`

Answer (score -1):

You can try with `TO_CHAR(date, 'MON')` for the months and `TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYY')` for the year.
The query will be

```
select EMP_NAME where TO_CHAR(C_DATE, 'MON') = month and TO_CHAR(C_DATE, 'YYYY') = year
```

And in php you'll have to manage the date to get year and month and pass them to the query

```
$dt = new DateTime("March 2014");
$month = $dt->format("m"); //03
$year = $dt->format("Y"); //2014

//Here connect to the db..
$db->query("SELECT EMP_NAME FROM yourTable WHERE TO_CHAR(C_DATE, 'MON') = :month AND TO_CHAR(C_DATE, 'YYYY') = :year");
$db->bindParam(":month", $month);
$db->bindParam(":year", $month);
```

Comment: can you write the query as we write in oracle 10g

Comment: I need to know where the date is stored in the db. Add the structure of the emplyees table on the previous post

Comment: I have added. Please check

Comment: `TO_CHAR(C_DATE, 'MON')` will return `MAR` not `03`. If you have to use this method it would be better to use `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM c_date) = 3 AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM c_date) = 2014`.